# After I have removed vertices, error says "loop in parent"

Tags: animation, objects, armature, bones

After I parent my model with the bone, it shows loop in parents.

Does anyone know of a solution?

[image]

[**The .blend file**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33520)

Comment: Try including images of what you have and some hint of what you are expecting.
Please don't put links that require permission to download. Use Pasteall.org/blender then add the link to the question.

Comment: Sorry i first time using this to ask question.

Answer (score 5):

I did not look at .blend file, but I will explain Loop in parents. It means, so you are trying to make infinite loop of parents(which would cause .blend to crash immediately, so Blender has blocked it). So, if you have set your character as Parent of your Bones, you can't set bones as parent to your character, otherwise, the parentation principal will be infinite loop. You can try selecting Bones and doing ALT + P and then Click with LMB on Clear Parent. Then do the same with char(optional). After that parent char to Bones. Hope this helps.